# Reading an array from a php extension (simple read )

Tags: php, php-extension

I am working by now to create a php extension for BladeRF card and i have an array to read from the extension like that:

```
 if (zend_parse_parameters(ZEND_NUM_ARGS() TSRMLS_CC, "a", &arr) == FAILURE) {
            RETURN_NULL();
         }
```

But my problem is how to loop this array in my extension?

```
for(zend_hash_internal_pointer_reset_ex(arr_hash, &pointer);zend_hash_get_current_data_ex(arr_hash, (void**) &data, &pointer)== SUCCESS;zend_hash_move_forward_ex(arr_hash, &pointer)) {

            //I know that i have to loop using this loop but my problem is how to recuperate all array field value in this loop

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [manual](http://devzone.zend.com/317/extension-writing-part-ii-parameters-arrays-and-zvals/#Heading5) describes it. Example:

```
for(
    zend_hash_internal_pointer_reset_ex(arr_hash, &pointer);
    zend_hash_get_current_data_ex(arr_hash, (void**) &data, &pointer) == SUCCESS;
    zend_hash_move_forward_ex(arr_hash, &pointer)
) {

     if (Z_TYPE_PP(data) == IS_STRING) {
         PHPWRITE(Z_STRVAL_PP(data), Z_STRLEN_PP(data));
         php_printf("\n");
     }

     /* and so on ... */
}
```

I'm not sure if this answers your question completely. Don't hesitate to request more information.

Here comes a full example:

*hello.c*

```
...

PHP_FUNCTION(hello_world)
{

    HashTable *names_hash;
    HashPosition pointer;
    zval *names, **data;
    int array_count;

    if(zend_parse_parameters(
        ZEND_NUM_ARGS() TSRMLS_CC,
        "a", &names
    ) != SUCCESS) {
        RETURN_FALSE;
    }

    names_hash = Z_ARRVAL_P(names);
    array_count = zend_hash_num_elements(names_hash);

    for(
        zend_hash_internal_pointer_reset_ex(names_hash, &pointer);
        zend_hash_get_current_data_ex(names_hash, (void**) &data, &pointer) == SUCCESS;
        zend_hash_move_forward_ex(names_hash, &pointer)
    ) {

         if (Z_TYPE_PP(data) == IS_STRING) {
             do_say_hello(Z_STRVAL_PP(data));
         }

    }

    RETURN_TRUE;
}


void do_say_hello(char *name) {
    printf("Hello %s!\n", name);
}

...
```

*hello.php*

```
<?php

hello_world(array('foo', 'bar'));
```

Comment: Thanks !! I see that but what i want is to recuperate the value of every cell to add it as entry to another function. this if test if it is string , i don't know if data contain the value or not

Comment: Can you show what you want to do giving an example in PHP code (or pseudo code)? (This is easier to understand than words and can then be translated into C)

Comment: for(zend_hash_internal_pointer_reset_ex(arr_hash, &pointer);
   zend_hash_get_current_data_ex(arr_hash, (void**) &data, &pointer) == SUCCESS;
    zend_hash_move_forward_ex(arr_hash, &pointer)) {

   status = Set_Lms_Frequency(dev,arr[0]);
  
  }
I want something like that, the first cell goes as entry of the function set_lms_frequency

Comment: Why do you need a loop if you want to access the first element only?

Comment: Do you want to pass an associvate array or a numeric array to the function. What should be the return value? You did said much about this.

Comment: just a numeric as it is simpler ! what do you mean return value ther's no problem in the return value the problem here i don't know how to read a simple array correctly that's all

Comment: Check the example. I'm just handling strings. You might need other types too, but it should be easy to adapt.